# Missing paragraph at bottom of page 1 in itext-generated document

Tags: itext, page-break

I have been using itext for some time without any troubles but I just noticed that I am missing a short paragraph at the bottom of page 1 in a generated document.  I added some additional white space earlier in page one and now I do see the missing text part way down on page 2.

I do have a footer.  What should I look for to diagnose this problem?

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE ( http://sscce.org ), as we don't know how you're creating the PDF. Also tell us which version of iText you're. If the most recent version, we'll consider it a bug and fix it. If you're using an old version (e.g. older than 1 year), please read http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq

Comment: I will work on an SSCE but it will take a little while.  I have a commercial license in process but I am running now with itext-1.3.1.jar, itextpdf-5.4.0.jar, itext-pdfa-5.4.0, and itext-xtra-5.4.0.jar.

Comment: I have an SSCE (a tar file) but I need to upload it somewhere or email it.  What is the best approach?

Comment: It still fails with 5.4.5.

Comment: I'm still working on this.  I had issued table.setSplitRow(false) and table.setSplitLate(true) as a way of preventing a row from splitting across a page break.  If I comment both of those out, the problem goes away too.

Comment: As documented in my book, using `setSplitRow(false)` will omit data that doesn't fit the row. This is by design, not a bug (although it can be perceived that way by people who don't read the documentation).

Comment: I missed that sentence in the book.  Thanks for pointing it out.